# Не изменяется Mac address сетевой карты

Tags: c#, сеть, cmd, mac-address

Хочу изменить мак адрес сетевой карты, для этого нахожу соответствующий интерфейс в реестре в ветке

```
 SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Class\\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}
```

сверив соответствующие DriverDesc названия. И перезаписываю поле NetworkAddress на свой, новый мак адрес. После, чего перезагружаю интерфейс, что бы изменения вступили в силу.

```
SelectQuery wmiQuery = new SelectQuery("select * from win32_networkadapter where Name='+NameInterface+' ");
            ManagementObjectSearcher searchProcedure = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery);
            foreach (ManagementObject item in searchProcedure.Get())
            {
                item.InvokeMethod("Disable", null);
                item.InvokeMethod("Enable", null);
            }
```

В реестре изменения происходят, в свойствах подключения в так же вижу новый мак адрес, однако при попытке вывести информацию в консоли через ipconfig /all, в некоторых случаях у меня остается старый мак адрес. Может есть какие-то ограничения на генерацию мак адреса?

Функция для генерации нового мак адреса:

```
public string GenerateRandomMac() {
        string temp = "";
        Random seed = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            int number = seed.Next() % 254;
            temp += number.ToString("X2");
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

Comment: *Может есть какие-то ограничения на генерацию мак адреса?* Два младших бита старшего байта должны быть `10`. См. OUI.

Comment: Спасибо, проверю чуть позже - отпишусь. Думаю в этом и есть проблема.

Comment: Проверил - в этом и была ошибка. Если оформите как ответ - отмечу)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Может есть какие-то ограничения на генерацию мак адреса?

Два младших бита старшего байта должны быть `10`.

См. [Уникальный идентификатор организации (Organizationally Unique Identifier, OUI)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_OUI).